# r join two lists and sum their values

Tags: r

I have two lists: x, y

```
> x
     carlo      monte simulation      model    quantum 
        31         31          9          6          6 
> y
      model      system temperature     quantum  simulation     problem 
         15          15          15          13          13          12
```

What function should I use to obtain:

```
simulation     model   quantum
        22        21        19
```

I tried to merge them like in example but it gives me an error:

`merge(x,y,by=intersect(names(x),names(y)))` produces:

> Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify uniquely valid columns

There's no argument in that function what to do with values. What would be the best function to use?

`intersect(names(x),names(y))` will give the names of resulting list, but how to summarize values together??

Comment: You cant merge them because the length differ in both columns

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the case to write colnames manually, because the list is one of many. And their lengths are different. I'm trying to use mapply, but still struggling.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Map` in base R to return a list.

```
Map("+", x[intersect(names(x),names(y))], y[intersect(names(x),names(y))])
$simulation
[1] 22

$model
[1] 21

$quantum
[1] 19
```

or `mapply` to return a named vector which may be more useful.

```
mapply("+", x[intersect(names(x),names(y))], y[intersect(names(x),names(y))])
simulation      model    quantum 
        22         21         19
```

Using `[intersect(names(x), names(y))]` will not only be subset the contents of x and y to those with intersecting names, but will also properly sort the elements for the operation.

**data**

```
x <- list(carlo=1, monte=2, simulation=9, model=6, quantum=6)
y <-list(model=15, system=8, temperature=10, quantum=13, simulation=13, problem="no")
```

Comment: Ok. I was so close with mapply. So that's the solution `mapply("+", x[intersect(names(x),names(y))], y[intersect(names(x),names(y))])`.  Thanks!

Comment: This seems pretty convoluted when merge actually does what he is asking. See answer below.

Comment: merge was a function that he tried to achieve the desired result. Using `mapply` or `Map` is more straightforward solution.

Answer (score 2):

simple names matching does the trick :

```
# subset those from x which have names in y also
x1 = x[names(x)[names(x) %in% names(y)]]
# x1
# simulation      model    quantum 
#          9          6          6 

# similarily do it for y. note the order of names might be different from that in x
y1 = y[names(y)%in%names(x1)]
# y1
#  model    quantum simulation 
#     15         13         13 

# now order the names in both and then add. 
x1[order(names(x1))]+y1[order(names(y1))]
# model    quantum simulation 
#    21         19         22
```

Comment: could someone explain the downvote?; the person who did! have the courtesy to give a reason too!

Comment: I just got one as well. A bit confusing.

Comment: @Imo I have been getting such strange responses from SO since the last few days. it's so irritating at times when they dont share an explanation

Answer (score 1):

Base function `merge()` should do this with no issue so long as your fields make sense, but you need to include `merge(..., all=TRUE)`, as in:

```
y <- data.frame(rbind(c(15,15,15,13,13,12)))
names(y) <- c("model","system","temperature","quantum","simulation","problem")
x <- data.frame(rbind(c(31,31,9,6,6)))
names(x) <- c("carlo","monte","simulation","model","quantum")

merge(x, y, by = c("simulation","model","quantum"), all = TRUE)
```

results in:

```
simulation model quantum carlo monte system temperature problem
1          9     6       6    31    31     NA          NA      NA
2         13    15      13    NA    NA     15          15      12
```

Here you actually have data frames of length 1, not lists.